# How to open HTML link and click button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

At work we have 7 tools that I have to launch every morning. All the tools are on web pages.

So I have to open 7 links and click several buttons to launch the tools.

I would like to automate this operation. I used a C# code (similar to this one) which works fine

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Navigate("https://www.google.co.in");
//Wait for page to load
while (ie.Busy) 
{
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
dynamic allLinks =     ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)ie.Document).getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement link in allLinks) {
    //Do some validation to find out the required link
    if (link.href.Contains("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin")) {
        link.click();
    }
}
```

But actually we are not allowed anymore to use C# for licence reasons...

Is there any way to do that in HTML/Javascript ? (Open a link and click a button on it)

I'm not asking someone to do the work for me, but if you just have a nice tutorial or tip to look at it will be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript and use

```
window.open("www.url.com","_self")
```

to open the links.

You can find more info on window.open @ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. I still need to click some buttons on each page. Is that possible please ?

Comment: Hi @ThomasCarlton, I do not see it a good idea to invoke the click event. 

But nothing is impossible. So you can use apply() method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for this:

var elem = document.getElementById("linkid");
if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
    elem.onclick.apply(elem);
}

My suggestion is to wrap up your logic into a method and invoke it from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a selenium framework, have a look at this one for example
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

http://webdriver.io/ this is for Node.js

and here's a tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-webdriver-using-the-javascript-bindings--cms-21855

Answer (score 0):

You could just set-up your browser to [open all 7 as home pages](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/set-multiple-sites-homepage-internet-explorer-9) when it starts up.

Comment: That's an interesting tip. However I still need to click some buttons on each page.

Comment: Why? Aren't these seven sites on the web? With unique URIs?

Comment: Yes they are. But for every page, I have to select manually some criterion and click "Load" to load the data I'm interested in.

Comment: I think you're probably looking at a Javascript/JQuery solution - can you be more specific about the things you have to do to get the pages loaded?

Comment: I first type the page adress (which is the first operation easily automated), and then I fill a text box, then hit one button (This is where I'm struggling).